# Can I replace 3-way switches with 4-way switches?

Tags: electrical

Can I replace 2-3way switches with 2-4way switches as I have a couple of new 4ways just sitting around and the 3way switches are the older style ( every other switch in the house is the new style)

Comment: Seems like a strange question as most 3-way switches can be installed as 4-way switches (multi).  The only time I've seen this not be the case is with a z-wave device, but I don't do this kind of stuff often.  What exactly are you trying to replace and with what?

Comment: Right now I have toggle style 3way switches, but all others in the house are the new push switches. I have new 4way push switches and was just wondering if I can replace the 3 with the 4.

Comment: my guess is the toggles you have can be used as 4-ways as well; but that's not really your question.  bcworkz pretty much answers your question; one connection on your 4-way will just be left empty.

Answer (score 11):

Sure, a 4-way is essentially two 3-ways in one device. Usually a 4 way switch has 2 (IN) screws and 2 (OUT) screws. Using one of the (IN) terminals is the same as the common terminal on a 3 way. And using the (OUT) terminals is the same as the traveler terminals on a 3 way. Connect the travellers to the (OUT) terminals, then connect the power or light wire to one of the remaining (IN) terminals, leaving the other empty.

[image]

Background Information (if anyone cares)

The following illustration demonstrates the internal workings of each type of switch in a conventional installation. You should be able to see how a 4-way (middle )is functionally two 3-ways (left and right switches) overlaid.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

A fourwsay is not two threeways in one device.  It can be described as complimentary single pole switches.  It is possible but you would not leave a terminal unused.   You would tie the common wire to the two  non-continuos terminals.

Comment: A four-way can easily be made from two three-ways by tying their handles together and adding a couple of jumpers. (Of course you would only do this on a laboratory breadboard, not in your home wiring.) - So a four-way is *like* two three-ways, in an essential way.

Answer (score -4):

A 4way switch will not work in place of a 3way. The common toggle (in), whether up or down on a 3way switch, comes in contact with both switch leg (out) terminals. A 4way switch will not accomplish this. The 4way is more like two "separate" single gang switches, they will not work in unison as one.

Comment: This is just wrong. A four-way switch can easily be used as a three-way switch. bcworkz has even provided a diagram showing how to do it.

Comment: No @Community this cannot be improved with additional details. It is fundamentally wrong. It can only be "improved" by being re-written to a correct answer, a definitive one of which was already nearly eight years ago.